# how to create an xml spring configuration file

Tags: spring

Using SpringToolsSuite4 I can create a maven project but I don't know where to click to create an xml configuration file for my beans. I'm too scared to copy https://java2blog.com/spring-xml-configuration/ this guys code because I don't know how to read what their config file.

Comment: File> new(?)>XML!

Comment: Why XML, though? The Spring team have been pushing hard for developers to move to Java Based configuration...